# Problem i dont understand with the DOMXPATH

Tags: php, file-get-contents, domxpath

I made a function to get class data from a website with the DOMXPATH. But I dont get any results. With any class of this site.

I dont know why, can anyone help me to get data from a class from this site.I want the search volume from a keyword for example.

Here is my Code

```
  $html= file_get_contents('https://app.neilpatel.com/de/ubersuggest/overview?keyword=whatsapp');


  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($html);     
  $xpath   = new DOMXPath( $doc );


  $spans = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"css-605ux8")]');
  print_r($spans);  

  foreach($spans as $item) {
  echo $item->nodeValue;


  }
```

Can anyone help me what I do wrong with this site?

Thanks alot

Comment: The site has very little static HTML content (look at the source of the page). All content is loaded asynchronously and so you cannot use `DomDocument::loadHTML` for that, as that only loads the initial HTML but does not execute the JavaScript referenced in that HTML.

Comment: okay i understand, is there another way to get the data out of the html (Javascipt)?